# How to access to a control in a form that lives in a panel

Tags: c#, forms, panel

I have a panel named panel1, two buttons named buttonLoad and buttonSave. All of these controls live in Form1.

There's another Form(Form2) which consist of a textbox named textbox1.

when the buttonLoad is clicked, the Form2 is loaded into the panel1.

After typing something in the textbox1 when I click the save button how can i get the text that was typed? ( I want to know how to get the textbox1.text which is in Form2 loaded to panel1)

Comment: I think I see this question at least once every hour. There's _A LOT_ of info here on SO or Google about getting textbox input from an other form.

Comment: Yes, There are a lot of tutorials on how to get a value, property or method from another form. But I'm taking about a form that lives in a panel. When the form is loaded into the panel I couldn't find a way to access it... Please help

Comment: Why not put the textbox directly on the panel? Form2 doesn't seem like much of a reusable object if its only control is the textbox.

Comment: there are 6 different Forms to be loaded in the panel. each Form has different controls. That's why.. Thankx.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting design, I suppose this is generally done using a `TabControl` which keeps the controls on all tabs in memory,  not only those on the visible tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to nail down with a code sample but from the description it sounds like you have a control within a form that you would like to access.

If the form is in a separate file, say an ascx that you place onto the page, then you will need to make sure the textbox control within that form is declared public, or you might need to make a publicly accessible variable within the ascx file that grabs the value out of the textbox.

It might be something like

```
Form2 myForm = new Form2();
string val = myForm.textbox1.Text;
```

if your textbox is publicly accessible or

```
Form2 myForm = new Form2();
string val = myForm.MyAccessorVarForTextBox1;
```

if you use a public variable that accesses a private textbox.

Hope this gives you something to start with.